# How can I add notes to the bottom of a table using knitr::kable?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

LaTeX has the ability to [add notes to the bottom of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table) using `tablenotes`, so it seems like `kable` might be able to easily implement this -- or maybe it already does, but I can't find any mention of this capability.

For example:
[image: Table notes at the bottom of a table]

Comment: You cannot, as [Pandoc's markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables) does not support this feature. You can add the notes below the table separately.

Comment: If you're willing to use `xtable` instead of `kable` to create your table, then [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9356118/496488) might provide a solution for you.

Comment: @eipi10: would xtable work for html output (with the notes)?

Comment: @FernandoHocesDeLaGuardia, you can get html output like this `print(xtable(mtcars), type='html')`. I assume you can add notes in a similar way to Latex output, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @eipi10 I tried the example in the link , but the note comes up in the first row once rendered (and the last on raw html in the console)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can actually do exactly this using Hao Zhu's awesome `kableExtra` package! As follows:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# LaTeX Table
 kable(dt, format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
   kable_styling() %>%
   add_footnote("Footnote 1", notation="alphabet")
```

[image]

> Check out the [GitHub](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra) repository for the full scope of everything `kableExtra` can do. It greatly extends the functionality of tables within both LaTeX and HTML with loads of extra features.

Comment: The 'a' describes a specific cell, Siberian husky. Is it possible also insert an 'a' in a cell as per the table of the question? Thanks!

Comment: To insert a superscript footnote number/letter/symbol in the row label, you can manually change the row name and add the appropriate notation as in `Datsun 710$^a$` for a `notation = alphabet` footnote. The dollar signs turn "math mode" on and off and the carrot ^ tells latex to superscript what follows.

Comment: For more on manually adding footnote marks to row labels, see Table Footnote section of manual: http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf