# Adjustment of horizontal lines is not working in xtableList

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I'm using the nice xtable package to create latex tables that are converted to PDF via Rmarkdown. To just have on horizontal line after the column names, the following is working fine:

```
tt <- diag(5)

print(xtable(tt),hline.after=0)
```

To explain colums and rows, I want to add a little text beneath the table. But if I follow the recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38273508/7546231) to use xtableList, adjusting the horizontal lines doesn't work anymore.

```
ttlist <- list(tt)

attr(ttlist, "message") <- c("Rows contain x", "Colums contain y")

print(xtableList(ttlist),hline.after=0)
```

I would be very happy for any suggestions on how to get xtableList to draw horizontal lines  at other places than the default ones of c(-1,0,nrow(x)).

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a different package (i.e. mine!), try:

```
library(huxtable)
ht <- as_hux(diag(5))
bottom_border(ht)[1,] <- 1
ht <- add_footnote(ht, "Rows contain x, columns contain y") # for example
```

Comment: that looks promising, thank you! i will check it out in the next days and report back